# Call JavaScript function from another JavaScript function cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, cordova

I want to use Cordova Facebook login plugin in my mobile app. I have 2 functions the first one to get the accesstoken and I pass that token to the second function to get the user data,but it does not work:

```
<script>
  var login =function(){
  facebookConnectPlugin.login(["email"],                
  function (response) {
     apiTest(response.authResponse.accessToken)
  },
    function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });                
  }

var apiTest = function (token) {        
        facebookConnectPlugin.api("me/? 
fields=id,name,email,gender&access_token=" +token,
        function (response) { alert(response.email + " " +response.name) },
        function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)) });
        }
</script>
```

I does not work with me, I don't know why? Please advise.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Take a look at this example from documentation: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin#get-access-token

Comment: what means "it does no work"? please be more specific.

Comment: nothing happens,I think there is an error but I cannot see it, I;m testing on my device